# How do I programmatically create a full-width Adaptive Card?

Tags: microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

This link specifies how to do this when using a JSON object:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-format?tabs=adaptive-md%2Cconnector-html#full-width-adaptive-card

```
{
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "body": [{
        "type": "Container",
        "items": [{
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "Digest card",
            "size": "Large",
            "weight": "Bolder"
        }]
    }],

    "msteams": {
        "width": "Full"
    },
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "version": "1.2"
}
```

I am instead, using the AdaptiveCard class to create the card.
The "msteams" property in the above-referenced JSON is a missing property on this class.
How do I add this property to my cards?

Answer (score 1):

So to do that in C# you need to pass a dictionary value in Adaptive card AdditionalProperties.

Here's the code snippet-

```
        var additionalProperty = new SerializableDictionary<string, object>();
        additionalProperty.Add("msteams", new
        {
            width = "Full",
        });
        var adaptiveCard = new AdaptiveCard(new AdaptiveSchemaVersion(1, 3))
        {
            Body = new System.Collections.Generic.List<AdaptiveElement>
            {
                new AdaptiveTextBlock
                {
                    Text = "Some Text",
                }
            },
            AdditionalProperties = additionalProperty
        };
```

This should work.!

Comment: Been offline for a bit, so didn't get a chance to respond.

I am using Typescript and tried to figure out how to implement @Hunaid's solution, but so far no success.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any way to set it via Typescript. Either you can use JSON format or programmatically can set via the C# code provided